# Porque move_uploaded_file NO sube archivo PNG

Tags: php, javascript, html, fetch

tengo un simple formulario para subir imagen, uso el Javascript y PHP. Funciona perfectamte cuando subo archivo JPG

```js
<?php
$destino = "img/producto/" . basename($_FILES["inpFile"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["inpFile"]["tmp_name"], $destino);
```

```html
<form class="form" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" id="inpFile" name="inpFile" /> <br />
      <button type="submit">Suibr Archivo</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
      const inpFile = document.getElementById('inpFile');
      myForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const endpoint = 'upload.php';
        const datos = new FormData(myForm);
        console.log(datos);
        fetch(endpoint, {
          method: 'post',
          body: datos,
        }).catch(console.error);
      });
    </script>
```

pero cuando intento subir un PNG no lo sube.

Comment: Pueden ser muchas cosas. O bien puede ser un tema de permisos (estaría bueno que digas sobre que plataforma estás trabajando: windows, linux, etc...). 
También puede ser que no tengas creada la ruta relativa "img/producto". Te recomiendo que no uses rutas relativas, tratá de utilizar rutas absolutas.

Avisame que plataforma estás usando. Si es linux, te puedo ayudar con el tema de permisos y de crear la ruta (si hiciera falta).

Comment: Estoy usando Windows y WampServer, lo extraño es que si funciona subiendo un JPG pero no funciona subo un PNG. Y la ruta “img/producto/” si existe

Comment: ¿Cuanto pesan los dos archivos que querés subir (tanto el que te deja subir, como el otro)? En apache hay una restricción sobre el tamaño de archivos. Como máximo, por default, te deja subir 2 mb por default. Se puede configurar.
Pero descartemos que sea ese el problema.

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el problema, pesaba 6mb, achique la imagen a 1mb y allí pudo subir.  Muchas gracias Federico